# why Attention layer not improving my model's performance

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am working on a multi-label text classification problem. following given is my samples description

```
x_train shape: (8066, 3000)
x_test shape: (1729, 3000)
x_valid shape: (1573, 3000)
```

i implemented an RCNN model which gives me 60 MiF score on my data but when i add attention layer to RCNN model still it is giving me same score of 60. I have tried almost every possible solution including tweaking of batch size, epochs, dropouts, batch norm, different size of hidden units but nothing improved score of my attention based model.
P.S
i tried to add attention layer before RNN, after RNN and after Concatenate layer too. Adding attention layer before and after RNN decreases models performance.

following i am sharing my model architecture without attention and with attention too.

**model without attention**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input, Bidirectional, LSTM
maxlen=3000
max_features= 50000
embedding_dims=100
input_length=maxlen

# Input for variable-length sequences of integers
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype="int32")
# Embed each integer in a 100-dimensional vector
x = layers.Embedding(max_features,
                            embedding_dims,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=maxlen,
                            trainable=False)(inputs)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

# Add 2 bidirectional LSTMs
x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, recurrent_activation='sigmoid'))(x)
b = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, recurrent_activation='sigmoid'))(x)

c1 = layers.Conv1D(128, 1, activation='relu')(b)
A1 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(c1)
M1=  layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c1)

c2 = layers.Conv1D(128, 2, activation='relu')(b)
A2 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(c2)
M2=  layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c2)

c3 = layers.Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu')(b)
A3 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(c3)
M3=  layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c3)

c4 = layers.Conv1D(128, 4, activation='relu')(b)
A4 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(c4)
M4=  layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c4)

c5 = layers.Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(b)
A5 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(c5)
M5 =  layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c5)


concat = layers.concatenate([A1, M1, A2, M2, A3, M3, A4, M4, A5, M5])

outputs = layers.Dense(50, activation="sigmoid")(concat)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

**Attention Layer**

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import initializers, regularizers, constraints
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer


def dot_product(x, kernel):
    """
    Wrapper for dot product operation, in order to be compatible with both
    Theano and Tensorflow
    Args:
        x (): input
        kernel (): weights
    Returns:
    """
    if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
        return K.squeeze(K.dot(x, K.expand_dims(kernel)), axis=-1)
    else:
        return K.dot(x, kernel)


class Attention(Layer):
    def __init__(self,
                 kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None,
                 W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None,
                 bias=True,
                 return_attention=False,
                 **kwargs):
        """
        Keras Layer that implements an Attention mechanism for temporal data.
        Supports Masking.
        Follows the work of Raffel et al. [https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08756]
        # Input shape
            3D tensor with shape: `(samples, steps, features)`.
        # Output shape
            2D tensor with shape: `(samples, features)`.
        :param kwargs:
        Just put it on top of an RNN Layer (GRU/LSTM/SimpleRNN) with return_sequences=True.
        The dimensions are inferred based on the output shape of the RNN.
        Note: The layer has been tested with Keras 1.x
        Example:
            model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
            model.add(Attention())
            # next add a Dense layer (for classification/regression) or whatever...
        """
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')

        self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
        self.b_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)

        self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
        self.b_constraint = constraints.get(b_constraint)

        self.bias = bias
        self.return_attention = return_attention
        super(Attention, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3

        self.W = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_W'.format(self.name))

        if self.bias:
            self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[1],),
                                     initializer='zeros',
                                     name='{}_b'.format(self.name),
                                     regularizer=self.b_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.b_constraint)

        self.built = True

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        # do not pass the mask to the next layers
        if self.return_attention:
            return [None, None]
        return None

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        eij = dot_product(x, self.W)

        if self.bias:
            eij += self.b

        eij = K.tanh(eij)

        a = K.exp(eij)

        # apply mask after the exp. will be re-normalized next
        if mask is not None:
            # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in theano
            a *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())

        # in some cases especially in the early stages of training the sum may be almost zero
        # and this results in NaN's. A workaround is to add a very small positive number ε to the sum.
        # a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True), K.floatx())
        a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())

        a = K.expand_dims(a)
        weighted_input = x * a
        result = K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

        if self.return_attention:
            return [result, a]
        return result

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        if self.return_attention:
            return [(input_shape[0], input_shape[-1]),
                    (input_shape[0], input_shape[1])]
        else:
            return input_shape[0], input_shape[-1]
    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        return config
```

**Attention model**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input, Bidirectional, LSTM
maxlen=3000
max_features= 50000
embedding_dims=100
input_length=maxlen

# Input for variable-length sequences of integers
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype="int32")
# Embed each integer in a 100-dimensional vector
x = layers.Embedding(max_features,
                            embedding_dims,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=maxlen,
                            trainable=False)(inputs)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

# Add 2 bidirectional LSTMs
x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, recurrent_activation='sigmoid'))(x)
b = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, recurrent_activation='sigmoid'))(x)

c1 = layers.Conv1D(128, 1, activation='relu')(b)
A1 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(c1)
M1=  layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c1)

c2 = layers.Conv1D(128, 2, activation='relu')(b)
A2 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(c2)
M2=  layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c2)

c3 = layers.Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu')(b)
A3 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(c3)
M3=  layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c3)

c4 = layers.Conv1D(128, 4, activation='relu')(b)
A4 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(c4)
M4=  layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c4)

c5 = layers.Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(b)
A5 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(c5)
M5 =  layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c5)


concat = layers.concatenate([A1, M1, A2, M2, A3, M3, A4, M4, A5, M5])
reshape_layer = layers.Reshape([1, 1280]) (concat)

att = Attention()(reshape_layer)
batch= layers.BatchNormalization()(att)
outputs = layers.Dense(50, activation="sigmoid")(batch)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Kindly guide me, shall be thankful

Comment: The attention layer works with a special kind of embedding most of the time and that is Positional Embeddings, when you are putting attention, in the beginning, it is disturbing the sequence of input so, therefore, LSTM doesn't perform well on the output of the attention layer. Instead of a single Attention layer try to use tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D() or tf.keras.layers.mha() it will definitely improve your model results.

Comment: Mohammad Ahmed, thank you for your kind comment. you mean i should use one tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D() layer along with keras attention layer? instead of individual RNN and CNN layers? moreover attention should be right after embedding layer or after tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D() layer?can you kindly write few lines of code for this suggested model, so that i get cleared.

Comment: First, let me know what kind of problem are you solving. then I can help.

Comment: Its clinical text classification, automatic labeling of clinical text (multi label text classification)

Comment: I have added a code please try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes try this, I have removed most of the things and then add some the things, Bi-directional LSTM most of the time in classification performs as equal to LSTM. SO, I removed it, and then I add Multihead Attention Layer. I have run this model and this is working fine. But one thing to notice here and that is your input shape which should be -> (Batch-size, sequence-length, embedding-dims) and your embedding-dims should be divisible by number of heads.

```
# Here onething to notice, your data should have the shape -> (Batch-size, sequence-length, embedding-dims)

x = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(8, key_dim=100, dropout=0.1, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.1))(inputs , inputs)
x = layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, recurrent_activation='sigmoid')(x)
b = layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, recurrent_activation='sigmoid')(x)

c1 = layers.Conv1D(128, 1)(b)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.activations.relu(c1)
z1 = tf.keras.layers.add([b , c1])

c2 = layers.Conv1D(128, 1)(z1)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.activations.relu(c2)

z2 = tf.keras.layers.add([z1 , c2])

c3 = layers.Conv1D(128, 1)(z2)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.activations.relu(c3)

z3 = tf.keras.layers.add([z2 , c3])

c4 = layers.Conv1D(128, 1)(z3)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.activations.relu(c4)

z4 = tf.keras.layers.add([z3 , c4])

c5 = layers.Conv1D(128, 1)(z1)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.activations.relu(c5)

z5 = tf.keras.layers.add([z4 , c5])

z5 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D()(z5)
z5 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(z5)
z5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(z5)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="sigmoid" , kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.1))(z5)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Comment: i tried your code but unfortunately following is output-----> 
 `Epoch 1/50
1009/1009 [==============================] - 851s 794ms/step - loss: 16.4049 - f1_m: 0.0231 - val_loss: 4.4994 - val_f1_m: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/50
 113/1009 [==>...........................] - ETA: 11:09 - loss: 4.5078 - f1_m: 0.0000e+00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Comment: Oh yeah! that's bad.

Comment: Remove MultiheadAttention and LSTM Layers just use Conv1D.

Comment: i have already tried conv1d its not performing well. my previous design RCNN+CNN performed well now i want to improve results by attention means

Comment: Your inputs are in text format or in integers?

Comment: inputs are in integers

Comment: Can you please show a chunk of data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249480/discussion-between-raz-and-mohammad-ahmed).